# Confusing fact in a solution

Tags: real-analysis

So, I was reading a solution to one of Rudin's exercises. And there was mentioned a strange fact, something like this: if ${ a_{n} }$ is a sequence and $A = sup(a_{n})$, then there exists $K$ such that for any $x>0$ we have for all $m>K$ that $|a_{m} - A|<x$. Is this true? I doubt it, cause the definition of a supremum of a sequence does not imply that as far as I know. I may be wrong with my conclusions, so there is a link to the proof: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zocemh&s=9#.XIukmaAzaUk

Answer (score 1):

That sure sounds like an error, because the sequence
$$
x_n = \begin{cases}1 &\text{$n = 2^k$ for some integer $k$}\\
0 & \text{else} \end{cases}
$$
has a supremum of $1$, but fails the condition for $x = \frac12$.

Comment: I attached link to the proof, can you check it? I may be wrong... It is like I don't understand something there in my opinion.

Comment: Yup. That proof is wrong, unless we know something else about the sequence (like "it's increasing". Try working through each step with my example above to see where it fails.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that example and failure. Is it possible to be true if we know that the sequence has a converging subsequence? Edit: ah, no, it is foolish of me I guess.

Comment: I think that perhaps you're suffering from gullibility -- being surprised that someone put something false on the internet.   Instead of that, perhaps you should go back and work harder on the original exercise rather than digging up wrong solutions. ;) And if you end up really stuck, post the original question here, along with the things you've tried, and perhaps someone who's good at analysis (i.e., not me!) will give you a push in the right direction.

Comment: that is a good idea. Generally I tend to solve and work on them myself but the exercise seemed so unclear that I could not even see a path which would go to the correct answer. That is my flaw sometimes that I don't follow paths and dive deeply in some cases and I am working on it to improve myself.